# How do I use prepared statements for inserting MULTIPLE records in SQlite using Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

How do I use prepared statement for inserting MULTIPLE records in SQlite using Python / Django?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Official Python library documentation: [Cursor objects](https://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)

Python's SQLite libraries don't have prepared statement objects, but they do allow you to use parameterized queries, and to provide more than one set of parameters.

Edit: An example of `executemany` as requested:

```
values_to_insert = [(1,"foo"), (2, "bar"), (3, "baz")]

cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO some_table ('item_num', 'item_name')
    VALUES (?, ?)""", values_to_insert)
```

Comment: @Amber: thank you for your answer. I had missed one important point i.e. it was insertion of MULTIPLE records.. "execute()" allows only one query to be execute.. so won't work for me :)

Comment: @mahendraliya which is why `.executemany()` exists: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany

Comment: @Amber: i went through executemany() as well but sorry to say I am quite new to both python and sqlite. My doubt is like if I have, say a list of filenames which I have prepared by appending values inside a list object, then how can I use it with executeMany.. is it like simply passing the list object (say fileList) to executemany()?.. Any code snippet would be really appreciated.. thanks.

Comment: @mahendraliya - added an example of `executemany` usage, as requested.

Comment: @Amber: your code worked very well for me.. BUT I get errors when I try to run executemany() for values having non-english characters.. this worked earlier with executescript().. I don't know why it fails with executemany()..? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know how to check for the encoding, can you please suggest how can I test it? The exact error obtained is : "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings."

Comment: I solved the error by using con.text_factory = str; Thanks for your all help and coming back again to the question

Answer (score 9):

You can use executemany() and pass an iterator object, e.g. to insert 100 integers and their squares:

```
def my_iter(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield i, i*i

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?, ?)", my_iter(100))
```